# Webpack html-loader returns full module definition

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Webpack, super cool and great, yay

also running it with grunt-webpack, omg so happy

whats more? some nice fellow made an inliner so I can require .html files, I sure am lucky

`var html = require("html!./some_template.html");`

only troublesome detail is that an html file containing

`<h3><%= any_variable %></h3>`

comes out as

`module.exports = "<h3><%= any_variable %></h3>"`

I feel like I must be missing some silly detail, otherwise maybe the thing to do is alter html-loader? It's a fairly trivial detail but I still feel like I'm misunderstanding this tool.

check it out https://github.com/webpack/html-loader/blob/master/index.js

as requested, from webpack.config.js, or in my case Gruntfile.js

`module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html" }
        ]
    }`

SOLUTION: turns out I can't actually read, `require("html!./some_template.html");` runs the loader, and then I was also running it in my config, so I wound up with commonjs declaration in my html.

Comment: Can you show the loader part of your webpack config?

Answer (score 8):

For others who are struggling like me here's the solution - https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/39jp8z/webpack_weirdness_no_love_at_stackoverflow/

Basically the html-loader is running twice!!

Remove either of the setting. (in webpack config or while importing)

Comment: This worked for me. Basically, we don't need the `html!` part in the require statement. Just `require("./some_template.html");`

Answer (score 2):

It is explicitly coded to do that - https://github.com/webpack/html-loader/blob/master/index.js#L71

You could contact the author through github and/or file an issue there?